# Add column with counts of another

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` that looks like the following where the `gender` column is a `factor` with two levels:

```
gender    age
m         18
f         14
m         18
m         18
m         15
f         15
```

I would like to add a new column called `count` that simply reflects the number of times that `gender` level appears in the data frame.  So, ultimately, the data frame would look like:

```
gender    age    count
m         18     4
f         14     2
m         18     4
m         18     4
m         15     4
f         15     2
```

I know that I can do `table(df$gender)` that gives me the number of times the factor appears, but I do not know how to translate those results into a new column in `df`.  I'm wondering how can I use the `table` function--or is there a better way to achieve my new column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try `ave`:

```
# first, convert 'gender' to class character
df$gender <- as.character(df$gender)

df$count <- as.numeric(ave(df$gender, df$gender, FUN = length))
df
#   gender age count
# 1      m  18     4
# 2      f  14     2
# 3      m  18     4
# 4      m  18     4
# 5      m  15     4
# 6      f  15     2
```

**Update following @flodel's comment - thanks!**

`df <- transform(df, count = ave(age, gender, FUN = length))`

Comment: I tried this and it populates the count column with NAs. After I run the command I get the message "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)".  The warnings look like: "In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 2L) : invalid factor level, NAs generated".  I double checked the column and it is in fact a factor.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully. If you convert 'gender' to a character it works. I edit my question. Cheers.

Comment: You can do `dat <- transform(dat, count = ave(age, gender, FUN = length))` and not have to modify the gender class.

Comment: @flodel, thanks a lot for your comment! I rarely use `transform` - time to start it seems! Cheers.

Comment: Well, `transform` is just to make things pretty. The problem you were having with `gender` being a factor is handled by not using `gender` but `age` as the first argument to `ave`.

Comment: @flodel - I misread the question, then your code. Sorry. Not my day...

Answer (score 7):

Since `gender` is a factor, you can use it to index the `table` output:

```
dat$count <- table(dat$gender)[dat$gender]
```

Or to avoid repeating `dat$` too many times:

```
dat <- transform(dat, count = table(gender)[gender])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr) 
ddply(dat,.(gender),transform,count=length(age))
  gender age count
1      f  14     2
2      f  15     2
3      m  18     4
4      m  18     4
5      m  18     4
6      m  15     4
```

Answer (score 1):

And a `data.table` version for good measure.

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

Once you have the `data.table`, it's then a simple operation:

```
df[,count := .N,by="gender"]
df

#   gender age count
#1:      m  18     4
#2:      f  14     2
#3:      m  18     4
#4:      m  18     4
#5:      m  15     4
#6:      f  15     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the counts and then do something like this, but that's not exactly elegant.

```
m.cnt <- length(which(df$gender == "m"))
f.cnt <- length(which(df$gender == "f"))

df$count <- NA
df$count[which(df$gender == "m")] <- m.cnt
df$count[which(df$gender == "f")] <- f.cnt
```

Alternatively you can use plyr but this results in recalculating the same thing over and over again, which might not be worth it since you only have 2 factors.

Comment: This is a good solution but is not practical for me. I used gender as an example, but the factor I'm trying to count actually has > 1000 levels.